# How do you determine which backend is being used by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Either interactively, such as from within an Ipython session, or from within a script, how can you determine which backend is being used by matplotlib?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use the [`get_backend()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.get_backend) function to obtain a string denoting which backend is in use:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.get_backend()
'TkAgg'
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way to determine the current backend is to read `rcParams` dictionary:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print (matplotlib.rcParams['backend']) 
MacOSX
>>> matplotlib.use('agg')
>>> print (matplotlib.rcParams['backend']) 
agg
```