# matplotlib figures disappearing between show() and savefig()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've kept a set of references to figures in a dictionary so that I could save them later if desired.  I am troubled that the saved figures are blank if invoke a `show()` command and look at them first.  Since the `show()` command blocks and I am not using a spyder-like interpreter, I have to close the figures before I get to `savefig()`

```
figures['myfig_1'] = figure()
...
figures['myfig_n'] = figure()
...

#show() #disabling this makes the problem go away
print "Saving:"
for fig in figures:
   figure(figures[fig].number)
   savefig(fig)
   print "Figure " + str(figures[fig].number) + ": " + fig
```

The print statement here has given me the indication that the dictionary is still intact, which I think means that I have not lost the figure references (they are still returning meaningful numbers in their `.number` attribute.)

Another twist I have noticed is that when I have done a similar thing in a class, storing the dictionary as a member and dividing the store and save functions into their own methods, this does not happen.  Is there something about the way I am closing the figures or storing the data which is making the figures loose their data?

Comment: I came up with an answer, but I'm locked out of adding it for 8 hours.  Rats...  The short version is that I changed my rendering backend to 'TkAgg' for now until I can figure out how to get Qt4Agg to behave the way I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#use-show), whether or not the drawing elements are destroyed from `show()` depends on the [backend](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#what-is-a-backend), and the version of matplotlib.  Not having the figures destroyed seems to be available with version 1.1.0.   To figure out [which backend is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580027/how-do-you-determine-which-backend-is-being-used-by-matplotlib), use the `get_backend()` function.  In my case, I was using the Qt4Agg backend.  By invoking the TkAgg backend, with the call `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` the figures were not destroyed before the save.  Now to find out how to change the behavior of the Qt4Agg...

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize that... The backends I use (mostly TkAgg) don't destroy the figure when you call show.  I wasn't aware that some did. I just jumped to the assumption that you were clearing the figure when you called `figure(figures[fig].number)`.  Regardless, I do find it much easier to stick to the OO interface and not rely on making figures active.

Comment: Incidentally, you should probably mark your answer as corrected, as you solved your own problem. It's perfectly acceptable to do so, though I believe you'll have to wait 2 days to mark your own answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Yep, it's telling me I still have 23 hours to mark my own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, in cases like this don't use the interactive matlab-ish state machine interface to matplotlib. It's meant for interactive use.

You're trying to make a figure "active", and creating a new figure instead. It doesn't matter which figure is active, if you just retain the returned figure and/or axis objects and use them directly. (Also, don't use wildcard imports! You *will* regret it at some later point when you're maintaining your code!)

Just do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figures = {}

figures['a'] = plt.figure()
ax = figures['a'].add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), 'ro-')

figures['b'] = plt.figure()
ax = figures['b'].add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), 'bo-')

plt.show()

for name, fig in figures.iteritems():
    fig.savefig('figure-%s.png' % name)
```

Comment: My newness is coming out here, I did not even know there was such a slick way to iterate the keys and values simultaneously.  I also agree on the wildcard import issue.  I'm in a new environment with a 'git er done' culture.  Additionally to opening the possibility of name collisions, it makes it harder to learn where functionality is coming from.

Comment: I've changed my ways, now using the .iteritems() approach, but I'm running into the same problem: after a show(), the figures seem to be deleted after I close the interactive window. The interpreter is stopping on the .savefig command and goes through a call stack of print_figure.draw() draw.update() where it tells me the underlying c/c++ object has been deleted.

Comment: The "state machine" approach appears to work.  Without the pyplot.show(), the figures are being recalled and saved properly.  If they are shown, then closed, then they are lost.  I don't know if this is part of the intention of pyplot.show() but it seems to be what is happening.  I don't know if it is a factor, but I am importing a package called pylab which I presume is giving me pyplot, but I don't really know.