# How do I configure the behavior of the Qt4Agg backend?

Tags: python, pyqt, matplotlib

[In an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019776/matplotlib-figures-disappearing-between-show-and-savefig) I learned that the behavior on `show()` was dependent on the [backend](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#backends) in use by matplotlib.  At that time I was looking for a way to keep `show()` from deleting the drawing elements of a figure, concluding that by switching from Qt4Agg to TkAgg, the drawing elements would be preserved even if the figures were closed.  I would like to increase my superpowers by learning, if possible, how to configure the Qt4agg backend to behave as desired.

Comment: Specific questions about matplotlib (or any particular package) are probably best put to a suitable mailing list - after looking at the documentation for answers. For matplotlib, the -users list is here: https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=matplotlib-users

Comment: Then why do we have a "matplotlib" tag?

Comment: I guess "best" just meant that you have a higher change of getting answer from the devs -- in case they are not addicted to SO yet.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to exercise extra control over the backend, just create the figures and keep references to them yourself, as shown in the highest-rated answer to your first question. The problem with trying to manipulate the backend, as you are asking to do here, is that the backend is not *intended* to hand your figures back to you intact once you have looked at them; that's not normally the backend's job. See:
[matplotlib figures disappearing between show() and savefig()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019776/matplotlib-figures-disappearing-between-show-and-savefig/6020293#6020293)

Comment: Link-only answer to another SO question