# Python not showing plots

Tags: python, plot, ipython, spyder

When I run the following code, plots don't show up even though I am not getting any error messages.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot = ([1,2], [1,2])
plt.show()
```

I tried the following
1) Change Spyder->Preferences->Graphics backend = Automatic (Reset kernel)
2) 
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
Got error: "no effect because the backend has already been chosen"

I am using Python 3.6 with Spyder that comes with Anaconda

Comment: Do you need `%matplotlib inline` at the top?

Comment: What happens when you do `matplotlib.get_backend()`?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3580027/2988730

Comment: When I add import matplotlib print(matplotlib.get_backend()), I get agg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an error in your code, it must be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2], [1,2])
plt.show()
```