# %matplotlib inline gives the same result with or without it on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, magic-function

So I went through some questions being posted about the usage of %matplotlib inline function in Jupyter Notebook, I do understand that "%matplotlib inline sets the backend of matplotlib to the 'inline' backend" & "When using the 'inline' backend, your matplotlib graphs will be included in your notebook, next to the code". But, I don't see any difference in my plot results with or without the use of "%matplotlib inline". Can someone explain this to me if I am misunderstanding something? Here's a simple code I have tried:

[Graph with %matplotlib inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIlSb.png)

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([[0,0],[1,1]], linewidth=4, label='random diagonal')
```

In the next code, I just took off the [%matplotlib inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LQgu.png) and it gives still gives me the same result. What is the point of using or not using the "%matplotlib inline" function then?

Comment: Seems your notebook is configured to use the inline backend by default. In that case you don't need to set it again.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yeah it makes a lot more sense if it's true. Is there a way I can check this?

Comment: [`import matplotlib; matplotlib.get_backend()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580027/how-do-you-determine-which-backend-is-being-used-by-matplotlib)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, figured that the problem comes from the notebook backend already set to inline. Once you run the code `matplotlib.get_backend()`, you can see the backend within the notebook is already set to inline by default. I am guessing this comes as a default now in Anaconda's version of Python 3.7's notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the backend running on the notebook. You can use a couple different output modes such as printing it to the notebook, a new window, or inline. A user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55266804/11313341) shows a couple of different ways it works according to the [documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html):

> To set this up, before any plotting or import of `matplotlib` is
>   performed you must execute the `%matplotlib magic command`. This
>   performs the necessary behind-the-scenes setup for IPython to work
>   correctly hand in hand with `matplotlib`; it does not, however,
>   actually execute any Python import commands, that is, no names are
>   added to the namespace.
>
> A particularly interesting backend, provided by IPython, is the
>   `inline` backend. This is available only for the Jupyter Notebook and
>   the Jupyter QtConsole. It can be invoked as follows:
>
> ```
> %matplotlib inline
> ```
>
> With this backend, the output of plotting commands is displayed inline
>   within frontends like the Jupyter notebook, directly below the code
>   cell that produced it. The resulting plots will then also be stored in
>   the notebook document.

If you change your command to `%matplotlib notebook` for example, the result should change. this command is to make sure it is set to inline if it is not already.