# Current value of %matplotlib in spyder

Tags: matplotlib, spyder

I am executing a script on spyder4, I want to either update old plots or add new figures depending on the state of `%matplotlib` something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([3,5])
if %matplotlib == qt:
    ax.set_data([],[])
else:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([5,6]
```

Is there a way to get the current value of `%matplotlib`, whether it is set as `qt` or `inline`?

Comment: `%matplotlib` sets the backend. So if you want to check which backend is in use, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580027/how-do-you-determine-which-backend-is-being-used-by-matplotlib

Comment: That's great! thank you